# ldisplayDetailForFilm is not a function.(In 'displayDetailForFilm)', 'displayDetailForFilm' is undefined

Tags: react-native, view, navigation

I am learning react native. I try to create a navigation between two views but it turns out that the error
**'TypeError: displayDetailForFilm is not a function. (In 'displayDetailForFilm(film.id)', 'displayDetailForFilm' is undefined) **
here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native'
import FilmItem from './FilmItem'
import { getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText } from '../API/TMDBApi'

class Search extends React.Component {
  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.searchedText = "" 
    this.page = 0 
    this.totalPages = 
    // l'API TMDB
    this.state = {
      films: [],
       isLoading: false,
            
    }
     _displayDetailForFilm = (idFilm) => {
      console.log("Display film with id " + idFilm)
    }
  }

  

// Components/FilmItem.js

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image,TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native'
import {getImageFromApi} from '../API/TMDBApi.js'

    
class FilmItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
 
    const { film, displayDetailForFilm } = this.props
      
return (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.main_container} onPress={() => displayDetailForFilm(film.id)}>
    ......
  </TouchableOpacity>
    )
    
  }
}
```

if you need more code to be able to reply to me please tell me

Comment: hi, same issue... still blocked into it. did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I’m doing the same course as you, I had the same problem... here’s my code is and the doc.

Search.js

```
class Search extends React.Component {

_displayDetailForFilm = (idFilm) => {
        console.log("Voir l'ID du film :" + idFilm);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', { screen: 'FilmItem'})
    }
}
```

Navigation.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Search from '../Components/Search'
import FilmDetail from '../Components/FilmDetail'


export default function Nav() {
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

    return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Recherche" component={Search} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={FilmDetail} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
 }
```

FilmItem.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import {getImageFromApi} from '../API/TMDB'


class FilmItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        const film = this.props.film
        const displayDetailForFilm = this.props._displayDetailForFilm
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={()=> displayDetailForFilm(film.id)} 
                style={styles.main_container}>
                {...}
              />
             {...}
             </TouchableOpacity>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/